# TRIGGER in oracle to prevent insert duplicate data

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm learning Oracle and I had a problem. I have my "Chat" table:

```
CREATE TABLE chat (
    id_chat      NUMBER,
    id_user      NUMBER,
    start_chat   DATE,
    end_chat     DATE
);
```

Now, I created a trigger so that it does not allow me to enter a "Chat" if an old one was already registered with the same id_user. This is my trigger:

```
create or replace trigger distChat
before insert on Chat
for each row
begin
if :new.id_user = :old.id_user then
        Raise_Application_Error(-20099,'YOU CAN'T INSERT DUPLICATED DATA.');
end if;
end distChat;
```

But still it still allows me to enter Chat with the same user code. Any help or recommendation to improve my trigger that does not work.

Thank you.

Comment: No, no,no,no no!

Comment: okey i know, like said @thatjeffsmith I must use an unique index for my id_user but if I want to insert the same id_user with another start_chat and end_chat, I must create the trigger just to make sure that the dates will not be located between the first register to start_chat and end_chat.

Comment: A user can't have more than one chat at the same time? I violate this rule every day. Also, this is a different question altogether.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith This is not the chat like facebook or insta, and yes I converted in another different question, can you help me with some idea? thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a TRIGGER.

Two reasons:

1. Oracle provides a mechanism for preventing duplicates
2. Triggers are expensive, and another database object to maintain

Do this

```
ALTER table CHAT ADD CONSTRAINT xpk_chat PRIMARY KEY ( ID_CHAT );
```

I don't know your data model, but I think you want ID_CHAT to distinguish a chat. If you do this for ID_USER, then a user couldn't ever have more than one chat...and who would want to use that system? If I'm wrong, just change the column referenced in the ALTER command above.

Now your table will have a constraint that prevents duplicate values on ID_CHAT column. This is called a PRIMARY KEY ([Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/cncpt/data-integrity.html#GUID-E1033BB9-0F67-4E59-82AC-B8B572FD82BB))

Additionally, you will have an INDEX, so querying your CHAT's by their ID value could be quicker.

P.S. Your Trigger isn't doing what you want it to do. If you were to do it with a trigger you would need to raise the exception if :new.id_user in (select distinct id_user from chat)...so basically if the ID resulting in the INSERT was already found in the table, there would be an exception. The beauty of the PK constraint is, that the database does this FOR YOU.

Comment: @thahjeffsmith in this part "if :new.id_user in (select distinct id_user from chat)" when I created my trigger, Oracle told me "subquery not allowed in this context"

Comment: @Stalinn don't use triggers to prevent duplicates

Comment: I've a doubt and I don't know if you can clarify it. I have one user with 01-01-18 like start_training and 05-01-18 like end_training, now I want to register the same user but this time with 03-01-18 like star_training and 06-01-18, these dates are different to the dates of the first register, but 03-01-18 is included between the dates range of the first register. It's necessary use a trigger or procedure or this part need to program?

Comment: if that's not valid data, then where is it coming from? passing comments back and forth w/o knowing your business rules and data model will get very frustrating for both of us